# Typescript Generic Function Type Literals

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, generics, literals

This is working, no problem:

```
type fun = (uid: string) => string 

const abc: fun = value => value

const efg = (callback:fun, value:string) =>callback(value)

console.log(efg(abc, "123"))
```

But if we go for generic, it will error:

```
type fun = (uid: string) => string 

const abc: fun = value => value

const efg = <T>(callback:T, value:string) =>callback(value)

console.log(efg(abc, "123"))
```

Error:

> This expression is not callable.   Type 'unknown' has no call
>   signatures.(2349)

[TypeScript Playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=7&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAZgrgOygXigCjgSwCYC4oDOwATpggOYCUKAfISWeVALABQbAxgPYJFQCGAIw754SVADd+AGzjRkdKbIhtOPPhBhNUAHgAqNNBxnTB-DgGtcegDRQlc3EVIVqC49NPmLaBxEqqrNy8XNIQAHTSXORomjFCHHYARACMAEwAzEmUAaxAA)

I read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html but it say nothing about Generic Function Type Literals.

I need to pass different functions as an argument, which is why I need this.

Is there any work around/hack or there is actually a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `T` type is not constrained, so it can be anything, you can pass there `number`, `string` etc. Its clear that you cannot call `number` like it would be function.

How you treat `T` in your code is as it would be function with `string` argument, therefor such constraint need to be given. Consider:

```
const efg = <T extends (a: string) => any>(callback: T, value: string) => callback(value)
```

Above `T` is constrained (by extend keyword) as a function which takes `string` and can return anything. It means that all functions like `string->number, string-> boolean, string->object` etc are ok.

We can go further and constraint it more (if you need) and say our function is only `string->string`, and exactly such interface is given by `fun` type. So lets extend `fun`:

```
const efg = <T extends fun>(callback: T, value: string) => callback(value)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/N4KABGAuCeAOCmYBmBXAdmAvGAFCglgCYBcYAzpAE75oDmAlFgHzlU20jhgDGA9mhTABDAEbdSqDNgBuQgDYpEmFrIXwufAZDDwktLGAA8AFR0APSPDSEyuIaQrU6jZcLTQmObvLkih3AGtSYwAaMFVFBzZnZh4fP0CcCPh6TghNMl45eAA6OV5aHF1C0W4wgCIARgAmAGZy+lSAXxBQCBgEZHQDPCIopwZYx3Y0nn5BUolumXlFWOSNce1igxNzS2tbSU9vOV9-ILBQ8Nn4fvYXFl39xOTUxYEs3PzC4pxSipr6xpAmoA)

Answer (score 0):

The following, based on [rxjs's UnaryFunction](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/290fa51c44881f25f2fe4cf9885028396c7fd74c/src/internal/types.ts#L6) might work for you.

[TypeScript Playground demo:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=80#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYbgIwxAHgBUA+ZAbwFgAoZO5ACgGcB7AVyiQC5kiBKHkQDcNAL40aoSLEQp0WXPgCSIAG4sA1tGJkqtegHoDyJTGRgAFiigQwHEOYCeABxSZWyEBAgATJuZZkHBQiABpkG2dsJGQ4EEdkAHdgS14aekYETAwcRA0eeWw8QlJw1Uw2CEEBWPixCWoaGDYQBDBgFgcfdmKAOTYAW2CoBnKMSp4QQeGaqaHoCnT6GzsoBzHK5AAqZAAmEWpxRupm1vbO5G62YoBlMChQAHNRiqrkJnunmo+HkEfF-R0Fb2ZAbFAAalBrwORxoCE6H2QEBgjwK2UUhDmwzIAF5Lj18P15lAhMgjMgAGqYYA+OEIsBIlG7NEKYoELHQXH4674O6-R6k8kqMY08JXW6fP50AZsREDOBgBAWcxWZCPCBeB4IJyuBrwkCI5GPADMLKKyjUmm0HKgXIY4sJ02gZVefGQOLIDogROGDAArHwhEA)

```
interface Callable<T> {
    (source: T): T;
}

interface CallableInvoker<T> {
    // If the return type also needs to be T, replace any with T
    (callback: Callable<T>, value: T): any
}


function doubleNumber(value: number): number {
    return value * 2;
}

function doubleString(value: string): string {
    return value + value;
}

const efg: Callable<number> = doubleNumber; // Valid
const efg2: Callable<number> = doubleString; // Invalid, doubleString  must match the generic type

const efg3: CallableInvoker<number> = (doubleNumber, value) => doubleNumber(5);
```

Comment: I know Function exist, but I cant manipulate it like I manipulate Generic, for example if I want to utilize the return type of that function or the type of that function argument or return the same function type to my HOC, can Function type help with this?

Comment: The following line isn't valid TS, but hypothetically, are you looking for something resembling this:
`const efg = <T>(callback: Function<T>, value:string) =>callback(value)` where `T` is the return type of the callback?

Comment: Ya, you can think something like that, or something like this

`const efg = <T>(callback:(argumentsTypeOfT)=>returnTypeOfT, value:string) =>callback(value)`

that allow me to do something with T

Comment: I think I've got something for you. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: `const efg: Callable<number> = {doubleNumber()}`

this will error if I try to call it

Comment: `Callable<number>` specifies a function. `doubleNumber` without brackets specifies the function. If you add brackets, `doubleNumber()` then that doesn't refer to the function, but to the result of invoking the function.

Comment: I've updated the code to include a new interface, `CallableInvoker<T>` which allows you to use the syntax you've specified earlier. 

Note however, that there's no requirement for any object that implements `CallableInvoker<T>` to actually invoke the callback on the parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211164/discussion-between-osh-and-tylim).

Comment: sorry, it was late night, I went to bed,  btw I found the answer, appreciate your help